# How do L2 norm and Jacobian act as a regularisation term to encourage smoothness in a deformation field?

Tags: computer-vision, image-processing, l2-regularization

How do L2 norm and The Jacobian act as a regularisation term to encourage smoothness in a deformation field? from the VoxelMorph original paper ([here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1809.05231.pdf)) they used Jacobian as a means to smoothen the deformation field, a similar paper ([here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2008.03949.pdf)) made use of L2 norm to smoothen the deformation field. However, I don't understand how this is achieved using either L2 norm or Jacobian. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL,DR Use the Jacobian to get smoothness and the L2 norm to limit the magnitude + they could be complementary.

I just skimmed at the paper (that you haven't really referenced) and the regularization term using the derivatives makes sense to make $\phi$ smooth. It's basically penalizing large changes between neighboring values of the registration field. Using the L2 norm would penalize the magnitude of the registration field, not the local variations.

Comment: That means taking the jacobian(derivatives, partial derivatives) measures the smoothness and then applying a penalty to the magnitude of the derivatives using L2 norm? is that what the statement "We use the L2 norm over the deformation field gradients as a regularization term to encourage the deformation field smoothness" means (I've included the links sorry about that)

Comment: Exactly, if the gradient or changes are small, the field is smooth.